# Does umount asynchronously release the underlying device?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, mount

I have some code that umounts a file system on a device and then immediately removes the device from device-mapper using the `DM_DEV_REMOVE` ioctl command.

Sometimes, as part of a stress test, I run this code in a tight loop of:

1. create the device
2. mount the file system on the device
3. unmount the file system
4. remove the device

Often, when running this test over thousands of iterations, I will eventually get the errno `EBUSY` when trying to **remove** the device. The umount is always successful.

I have tried searching on this issue, but mostly what I find is people having issues with getting `EBUSY` when umounting, which is not the problem I am having.

The closest thing to being helpful that I could find is that in the [man page for `dmsetup`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dmsetup) it talks about using the `--retry` option as a workaround for udev rules opening up devices when you are trying to remove them. Unfortunately for me though, I have been able to confirm that udev does not have my device open when I am trying to remove it.

I have used the `DM_DEV_STATUS` command to check the `open_count` for my device, and what I see is that the `open_count` is always 1 before the `umount` and when my test succeeds it was 0 after the `umount` and when it fails it was 1 after the `umount`.

Now, what I am trying to find out to root-cause my issue is, "Could my resource busy failure be caused by `umount` asynchronously releasing my device, thus creating a race condition?". I know that `umount` is supposed to be synchronous when it comes to the actual unmounting, but I couldn't find any documentation for whether releasing/closing the underlying device could occur asynchronously or not.

And, if it isn't `umount` holding a open handle to my device, are there any other likely candidates?

My test is running on a 3.10 kernel.

Comment: Technically you mount/umount a filesystem, not a device.  Try a sync() call (which should stall your program while data is drained to the device) before the umount().

Comment: @sawdust I tried a sync() and still saw the issue. I'm not writing anything to the file system so I'm not too surprised that it didn't make a difference. Also, shouldn't umount() not return until a sync() has been completed anyway? I will update the question to be a little more precise about file system vs device.

Comment: *"Also, shouldn't umount() not return until a sync() has been completed anyway?"* -- I haven't looked at source, but in theory, yes.  I was taught to type `sync` twice before unmounting a fs in Unix a long time ago.  So I thought it was worth a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Historically, system calls blocked the process involved until all the task is done (being `write(2)` to a block device the first major exception for obvious reasons)  The reason was that you need one process to do the job and the syscall involved process was there for that reason (and you could charge the cpu processing to that user's account)

Nowadays, there are plenty of kernel threads involved in solving non-process related issues, and the `umount(2)` syscall can be one of the syscalls demanding some background (I think it isn't as `umount(2)` is not frequently issued to justify a change in the code)

But linux is not a unix descendant, so `umount(2)` could be implemented this way.  I don't believe that, anyway.

`umount(2)` syscall normally succeeds, except when inodes on the filesystem are in use.  That's not the case.  But the kernel can be involved in some heavy duty process that makes it to alloc some kernel memory (not swappable) and fail in the request.  This can lead to the error (note that this is only a guess, I have not checked this in the code, you had better to look at the `umount(2)` syscall implementation) you get anyway.

There's another issue, that could block your umount process (or fail) in case you have touched someway the filesystem.  There's some references dependency code that makes filesystems capable of resist power failures in a consistent status (in linux, this is calles *ordered data*, in BSD systems it is called *software updates*, that makes erased files to not be freed immediately after `unlink(2)`.  This could block `umount(2)` (or make it fail) if some data has to be updated on the filesystem, previous to make the actual `umount(2)` call.  But again, this should not be your case, as you say, you don't modify the mounted filesystem.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. How are you suggesting that `umount(2)` is interfering with the `DM_DEV_REMOVE` ioctl call? The umount is always succeeding and it is only on the later call for removal of the device that I get an error.

Comment: well, I don't know exactly what you are doing.  Most probable things a device doesn't allow to be removed from a bus connector is that the device is busy (in use)  This has to do with kernel internals and is difficult to pursue.  Less when you post no code at all.  I'm afraid I cannot help you more without having a look at your program and being unable to trace anything.